# MonacaでfindMine()を使用してユーザのデータを取得するとき、どのようにして各ユーザを識別していますか？

Tags: monaca

Monacaのバックエンドを使用して、アプリ開発を行っています。
ログイン機能は使用していませんが、findMine()を使用してユーザのデータを取得しています。
findMine()でのユーザの識別はどのように行われるのでしょうか？

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

自分の場合はユーザーのoidを使って識別しています。下記のドキュメントに詳しいので見てみてください。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/javascript/cloud/user/#u-oid